# Send active sheet in google sheet as pdf by whatsapp to given number

Tags: google-sheets, whatsapp

I want to send the active sheet in google sheet as pdf by whatsapp to given number.
There will be number with country code in the active sheet. I want to send the sheet as pdf to that number via whatsapp.

I have this code from StackOverflow to email the document as pdf:

```js
// Define your variables here

var recipient="ronyantonyjoseph@gmail.com";
var subject=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var body="Hello,\n\nPlease find attached bill for the month.\n\nThank you,\nMoothedam RPS";
var nameOfSender="Moothedam RPS";

// End of the stuff you need to edit


// Below, the sheet is converted to pdf in a blob object and that object
// is sent by email with the email-parameters above.



// Other stuff 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
//var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
//var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId();

// Base URL
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

/* Specify PDF export parameters
From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
 */

var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
     + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
     + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
     + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
     + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
     + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
     + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
     + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {                                 
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

sheet_as_pdf_blob_document=response;


// Here we send the email

function sendReport() {
 
   var message = {
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    name: nameOfSender,
    attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }

   MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


//===============

//===============
```

But I am not having any idea how to send this using whatsapp

Comment: Do you mean WhatsApp Business API? yes, then you have to setup and verify your WhatsApp business account on Facebook look at the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview).

Answer (score 0):

Just read [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/messages) and after that do simple POST request:
On */v1/messages* with params type: document.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I am just a beginner here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).